# Changing a Kivy Widget Text

Tags: python, kivy

I am attempting to create a pong game using kivy.  However, I am running into issues when I try to end a game after someone scores 10 points.  Everything is working well except that I would like to show a Game Over text using a label.  I created a label and currently the text is set to an empty string, but it should change after someone scores enough points.

I have looked through the kivy documentation and searched stackoverflow but I have not found an answer for this(or at least not one that I understand.)

If someone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Here is my code:

.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock


count1 = 0
count2 = 0



class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)


    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        global count1
        global count2

        self.ball.move()

        #bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        #bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        #went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player1.score += 1
            count2 = count2 + 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

        if count1 or count2 >= 10:
            #
            #
            #
            #I don't know what needs to be placed here to change the third label's text


    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game



if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongPaddle>:
    size: 25, 200
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3/4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width-self.width
        center_y: root.center_y

    Label:
        id: game_over_label
        text: " "
        font_size: 100
        center_x: root.width / 2
        center_y: root.height / 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the same method to change the game over label that you use to change the score labels when the score changes.

If you add an `ObjectProperty` to `PongGame` in main.py:

```
end_label = ObjectProperty()
```

And in your kv file under `PongGame`, write:

```
end_label: game_over_label  # linking them up
```

You could add a function to `PongGame` class in main.py:

```
def check_score(self):
    scores = [self.player1.score,
              self.player2.score]
    for s in scores:
        if s == 10:
            self.end_label = "Game Over"
            return
```

Then in your `update` function, you could call this function any time the scores are incremented, for instance:

```
 self.player1.score += 1
 self.check_score()
```

and the same for `self.player2.score`

Answer (score 0):

one way to find the ID inside the tree is to put a "redirector" in the root of the widget

In .kv, right under PongGame:

```
        gameoverlabel: game_over_label
```

in .py under the " if count1 or count2 >= 10:" add

```
        self.gameoverlabel.text = "win"
```

hope this is helpful